# Bootstrap v4.1 - Collapse não funciona de forma correta

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap-4

Segue código:

```js
$('#collapseDescricao').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('[data-target="#collapseDescricao"]').text("Mostrar descrição");
});
$('#collapseDescricao').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
   $('[data-target="#collapseDescricao"]').text("Ocultar descrição");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDescricao" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Mostrar descrição
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseDescricao" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            <button style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Botão vermelho <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>

            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">bla blab bla balbalbalba</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Última atualização: 28/05/2018</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ou se preferir JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7g1xoq1/

O problema está no botão vermelho, quando eu clico nele, ele altera o título. O botão vermelho não pode alterar o título. O botão vermelho só serve para expandir "collpase" e não alterar título. Só pode mudar o título quando clicar `#collapseDescricao` e não `#multiCollapseExample1`.

Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que o evento `'shown.bs.collapse'` que você está trabalhando é propagante. Ou seja, o evento que ocorrer no *collapse* interno irá se propagar pelos elementos pais e, consequentemente, pelo elemento `#collapseDescricao`, executando novamente o código de alteração do título. Neste caso, uma maneira seria verificar quem foi o alvo original do evento com `event.target.id` e alterar o título apenas se foi o `#collapseDescricao`.

```
$('#collapseDescricao').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (event) {
  if (event.target.id == "collapseDescricao") {
    $('[data-target="#collapseDescricao"]').text("Ocultar descrição");
  }
});
```

Veja:

```js
$('#collapseDescricao').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'collapseDescricao') {
    $('[data-target="#collapseDescricao"]').text("Mostrar descrição");
  }
});
$('#collapseDescricao').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(event) {
  if (event.target.id == 'collapseDescricao') {
    $('[data-target="#collapseDescricao"]').text("Ocultar descrição");
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="mb-0">
      <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDescricao" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Mostrar descrição
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseDescricao" class="collapse">
    <div class="card-body">
      <button style="margin-bottom: 15px;" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Botão vermelho <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>

      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">bla blab bla balbalbalba</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Última atualização: 28/05/2018</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```